# Short story where a 'farmer' is told that he's actually an astronaut with false memories

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, astronauts

I am trying to remember the name of a specific short story.

It was about a man who is on a farm or farm-like house made of wood, sitting on his porch drinking something (beer?) As he does so, he sees a figure in a crop field or field of grass coming towards him.

He gets worried and pulls his gun out in fear that the figure is going to attack him. It stops after it gets a certain distance away from the man as the man is freaking out and I believe he starts talking to the man.

To make a long story short, the figure talks to the man and makes him realize his memories are false and that he isn’t a humble farmer drinking on a cool night, he was an astronaut who was lost and crash landed on the planet. The figure leads him to a ship which takes him back to Earth.  I can’t remember a lot of the plot twist and big details. I probably butchered some aspects of the story but I hope it’s enough.

Comment: Do you remember when you might have read it and what language it was in? Was it in a comic book or an anthology?

Comment: I know it was in English and I don’t recall it being in a comic book. I thought it might’ve been some kind of Lovecraft style short story but I can’t be sure. I’m sorry I’m having a hard time recalling.

Comment: Do you remember when you read this?  In a magazine or an anthology?  Also, try looking here: https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question to see if any of the suggestions there jog your memory; the more details you add, the more change we have to help you.  And don't give up if we don't have an answer right away; sometimes story id questions are answered days later, or even more...

Comment: It could’ve been in some kind of anthology but I can’t be sure. I don’t want to mislead anyone if they’re still trying to assist me. Thank you for all your help! If I remember anything that could help I’ll make sure to comment what I remember.